# A compact covered by a disjoint union of closed balls

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis

Let $B$ be a ball in $\mathbb{C}^n$. We know that the boundary of $B$ being compact, can be covered by a finite number of balls, say, $B_j\subset \mathbb{C}^n$ ($j=1,..., k$). My question is: How can we select $B_j$ to be **disjoint*** and such that the boundary of $B$ is included to the union of the closures of these $B_j$, i.e.
$$\partial B\subset\cup_{j=1}^k \overline{B_j}?  $$

Comment: Just take $j = 1$ and $B_1 = B$.

Comment: treble's comment shows that you are probably have some additional requirements. Are all balls assumed to be closed?

Answer (score 1):

You can easily find such a cover for $k = 1$. You can then add as many extra disjoint balls as you like. In fact, all valid covers will look like this. As $\partial B$ is connected and $\partial B \subseteq \bigcup_{j = 1}^k \overline{B_j}$ a disjoint union, it must be contained in exactly one of the $B_j$. The rest of the balls in the cover will be disjoint from $\partial B$, so they're essentially extraneous.